# How to fix P0128 and P0826 error codes for Chevrolet Malibu 2005?

Tags: chevrolet

Make: Chevrolet

Model: Malibu

Engine: 3.5L

Year: 2005

Error codes: P0128,P0826

Knowledge level: I know little about cars

Help needed: Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your coolant level. A P0128 is an insufficient coolant temperature code. If the the coolant level is OK, replace the thermostat.

The P0826 code is for the up shift down shift command for the buttons on the shift lever. This will not illuminate the check engine light. If the buttons work as normal this was an intermittent issue. There may be a ground issue or the switch it self is worn.